# What should I use for install in this distro?

Tags: apt, yum

I don't know how should I install apps with this distro:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.19.3.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm02.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Aug 7 21:33:29 EDT 2018
```

`yum`, `apt-get`, `rpm`, all say `command not found`

EDIT:

```
$ whereis rpm
rpm: /usr/lib/rpm /etc/rpm
$ whereis yum
yum:
```

EDIT 2:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mohana.server-host.name 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.19.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 7 21:33:29 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ head /etc/*-release
head: cannot open '/etc/*-release' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `locate -u`
`locate rpm | grep bin`?

Comment: You are running Cloudlinux. `yum` and `rpm` should work. What do you get from `wheris yum` and `whereis rpm`?

Comment: I'll edit my question answering your both questions

Comment: Better to use the output of `uname -a` (instead of /proc*version).

Comment: Also add the output of `head /etc/*-release`, please. If you're using a VPS of some sort, that may be the host system's kernel you're seeing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome, could you at least try to put some effort in your output. we don't really need to see that you misstyped `whereis` command.

Comment: @Kiwy hello. I just copypasted without notice it, then I put the correct one. I will edit the question with those outputs

Answer (score 2):

All: yum, apt-get, and rpm, require a `root` user.

What do you get from executing `whoami` ?

My guess is that you get `user`, not `root`. Log in as root and try

```
# rpm -ivh package
```

note that the `#` represents that the shell is running as `root`.

I am showing the `rpm` command as your whereis showed that rpm exists on your system.

Comment: I'm in a shared hosting (cloudlinux). How should I switch to root? I can't execute "su" or "sudo" (not found). There are folders for rpm but I can't use it, or don't know how...

Comment: Please ask your hosting company. @pmirnd

Comment: I did, I'm waiting for an answer from them, for now I'm asking here too